# Is Navratri celebrated in ISKCON?

Tags: iskcon, navrathri

I want to know if ISKCON celebrates Navratri. If they do how they celebrate it?

Comment: No! They don't. They don't consider any other God as God except Lord Krishna.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto that's not true. They consider Shiva to be identical to Vishnu ( curd to milk analogy) and even celebrate Shivratri( though still putting emphasis on Krishna).

Comment: @Rishx I personally attend iskcon programs. They don't celebrate navaratri or shivratri. May be some centres of iskcon might be doing. But officially, No. Secondly they don't think Shiva and Vishnu to be identical.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande I meant almost identical..here read how they define Shiva tattva http://www.iskconpune.com/mahasivaratri-festival-lord-shiva-tattva-and-position/

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande  correct me if i am wrong..but Prabhupada did celebrate Mahashivratri.

Comment: They do celebrate Navaratri (only at 1 or 2 places). They take her as Maya devi, the amsh of Krishna and worship her thus that way. Also, they worship Katyayani devi, as she is provider of Krishn loka and Krishnbhakti. Thus with the intention to gain her grace and cut through maya of samsara and get Krishn bhakti they worship her. So, yeah it's just a Vaishnava perspective. (Not those who call devi as Slave of Hari . Such people are jokers nothing more.)